# Почему не показывает список пакетов в MODX

Tags: modx

Почему не показывает список пакетов в MODX  revolution?
Это все что происходит. С чем это связано? Установил modx на локальный сервер xampp.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в xampp, так и не понял что там не так. Перешел на OpenServer